# sql statement "into outfile" not working with jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, into-outfile

I am attempting to add an "export to CSV" feature to a webapp that displays data from a MySQL database.  I have a written a "queryExecuter" class to execute queries from my servlet.  I have used this to successfully execute insert queries so I know the connection works etc however queries with the "into outfile" statement are simply not executing.  Here is my code,

**the java class...**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class queryExecuter {
    public void exportToCSV(String query) {
        DBase db = new DBase();
        Connection conn = db.connect(
               mydatabaseurl ,"myusername","mypassword");

        db.exportData(conn,query);
    }

}

class DBase {
    public DBase() {
    }

    public Connection connect(String db_connect_str,
            String db_userid, String db_password) {
        Connection conn;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_str,
                    db_userid, db_password);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            conn = null;
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public void exportData(Connection conn,String query) {
        Statement stmt;

        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            stmt.execute(query);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            stmt = null;
        }
    }
};
```

**The servlet...**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyExportServlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

     throws IOException, ServletException {

            String query = "select into outfile 'theoutfile.txt' * from mytable;";

            request.setAttribute("query", query);

            queryExecuter mydata = new queryExecuter();

            mydata.exportToCSV(query);

            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("ConfirmationPage.jsp");

            view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How did you conclude that it's not executing?

Let me guess, the file isn't written there where you expect it to be? This can be very true since your code uses relative disk file system paths like `'theoutfile.txt'` instead of absolute file system paths like `'c:/theoutfile.txt'` and analogously probably also `new File('theoutfile.txt')`.

A relative disk file system path is relative to the current working directory which **depends** on the way how you started the application (in commandline, as a service, in a server, etc). You should never rely on that when programming. Always use absolute disk file system paths.

In MySQL the actual root of the file is *probably* `c:/mysql/bin` and in webapp (the servlet) the actual root of the file is *probably* `c:/webserverinstallationfolder/webapps`. Nothing is sure with relative paths. Don't use them.

Comment: Thank you for the post I agree that relative paths are undesirable however I knew i could look in my MySQL data file for this simple test case since i had been executing the query directly from MySQL as a comparison. It seems that the real issue was my syntax which became jumbled while I was attempting to fix other things in my code.

Comment: In other words, your problem is already solved the other way?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd execute the query, and get a ResultSet. You can read the ResultSet and write the contents to file (with Java). This is Good(tm) because the Java server is normally on another machine as the database, and outfile is always on the database machine.

Apart from that wisdom :) you should do

```
select * into outfile
```

and not

```
select into outfile *
```

It may also be that you even have to do

```
select <entire_query> into outfile
```

see [Export to CSV with java](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jdbc/how-to-export-data-from-database-to-csv-file.html) and [MySQL Select syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: This can only be memory hogging in case of zillion of records.

Comment: Thank you! Somewhere along the line my sql syntax got jumbled